# Windows Task Scheduling : handling password change of execution account

Tags: .net, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, installshield

I've created an Installshield MSI which deploys several .NET console applications on a WinServer 2008 or  Vista (or later) Windows OS.

Installation process is run under local Administrator account.

During the installation process, the Installshield MSI prompts admin for password and use this password in a DOS command to create several scheduled task which will be programmed, run and executed under the administrator account.

I cannot help to feel there is a better way  to handle the creation of these tasks without asking a password or maybe using SYSTEM account and not creating a security hole.

Password can also expire for the installation account so I'm trying to figure out a more practical method to create these scheduled tasks.

The scheduled task must start .NET console applications which access  a SQL CE 4.0 database, create SMTP/POP3 client to external mail server, write files in local system HD.

Any link or help appreciated on how to perform best-practice scheduled task creation,

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are calling SCHTASKS to create the scheduled tasks.

**Option 1: use the SYSTEM account**

```
SCHTASKS /Create /RU SYSTEM /SC DAILY /ST 00:00:00  /TN "MyTaskName" /TR "MyConsoleApp.exe"
```

This is the recommended approach, but it has some limitations:

1. The program can access the database and email anonymously, or using another,
   pre-defined accounts.
2. The program doesn't need user-specific environment variables or registry settings.
3. The program has the appropriate file system permissions on the
   folder the application is writing to (the installation can take care of it).

**Option 2: use a specific account**

```
SCHTASKS /Create /RU username /RP password /SC DAILY /ST 00:00:00  /TN "MyTaskName" /TR "MyConsoleApp.exe"
```

If you rely on the user context of the application to login to the database and send email, the usual approach is to ask the user, at the beginning of the installation, to provide the credentials, and alert him that any future password change will require updating the relevant scheduled tasks as well. This also have other implications:

1. The 'disabledomaincreds' security policy must be set to false for
   the command to work (you can set it back to it's original value
   after running it). You can check and change the policy by reading
   and editing the registry value under
   `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`
2. The user must have the 'Logon as batch' permission. This can be done by running: ntrights.exe +r SeBatchLogonRight -u "username"

Comment: Thank you , this is the kind of response I needed.                                   I've implemented Option 2 and forgotten to take into account the policy value of the 'disabledomaincreds'.